# forever start app.js on windows opens a node command window

Tags: node.js, forever

I installed forever and forever-win globally using npm and started my app.js using 'forever start app.js' and this works but it opens a 'nodejs window' which I cannot close.

Is there a way in windows to start my application from commandline using forever without this nodejs window appearing?

Comment: have you tried looking at using Windows services for this or the start command?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Start it as a background process from command line.

`START /B program`

See [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background) for more details.

Comment: That didn't work, I still get the nodejs command window appearing.  I even put my program 'forever start app.js' into a .bat file called 'start.bat' and ran:  `START /B start.bat`